# Laravel trigger eager loading option only when if the value of another column is met the desired condition

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel eager loading and its working fine. However, I am thinking about is it possible to get that eager loading data only when the value from another column is set?

For example: I have a table,

```
reviews
=========
id
...
...
...
amenity_value_id
action // 1,2
```

And my query looks like:

```
$reviews = Review::with(['unit','amenityValue'])
            ->with(['unitAmenityValues.unit:id,unit_number'])
            ->where('property_id',$property_id)
            ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
            ->get();
```

Is it possible to use this `->with(['unitAmenityValues.unit:id,unit_number'])` only when `$reviews-> action == 2`. I mean fetch this `unitAmenityValues` details of a row only when the `action` value for that particular row is equal to `2`

I have been searching this for a while, however, I couldn't find any clue till yet. Is there any hacks to get it?

Comment: One sidenote, you don't need multiple `with()` clauses, just use one: `::with(['unit', 'amenityValue', 'unitAmenityValues.unit:id,unit_number'])`

Comment: Yeah, I know that, however, I want to load another with as per the condition. So, I was separating it. Anyway, thank you for your attention. Could you suggest any idea regarding the preoblem??

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of an approach, but maybe have a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#conditional-clauses; you can add a `->when( /* do something, like a different eager load based on a condition */ )`